# asp.net Pattern for handling View/Edit/Insert situations

Tags: asp.net, design-patterns, master-detail

I am an asp.net beginner and thinking about designing a website with a typically Master-Detail view. There is a GridView-Control which is displaying all Records and Detail view below to edit existing records, add new ones and display one in detail.

There are several controls in asp.net which can handle such situations: GridView in combination with DetailsView or FormView. But all these approaches do have in common that they seems to be designed for Rapid application development. I want to use my own DAL and so on, so I need to have full control over Insert/Update statements for example.

Whats the typical asp.net approach for dealing with this?
Should I create a UserControl for the Detail view which saves its state (View/Edit/... mode) on its own? Furthermore the view differs only slightly with its state (for example the Insert view does have one more Input-control than the edit view). It seems that the mentioned DetailsView and FormView cannot handle this either and so I have a lot of copy&paste like code.

I think thats all a pretty common situation. What do you prefer in those situations?

Comment: Have you tried [Dynamic Data Website](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc488469.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can bind manually data from your custom DAL to the DetailsView or FormView directly like so:

```
this.dvw.DataSource = new[] { DAL.GetObject(1) };
this.dvw.DataBind();
```

Or you can also use the ObjectDataSource, which wires up to your DAL object and invokes the method when it needs it.

You can also use a custom user control and load the data manually, which is an approach I have taken in my applications too.

It really depends on your architecture, what you want to achieve, how complex your object model is, and a variety of other factors.

Answer (score 0):

For the Master part, I build the interface by hand, I mean, creating textboxes, labels, etc. 
For the Details part, I use a editable GridView. This a tedious task.

Of course, you can use some scaffolding to generate ASP.Net code for your UI from the database model.
You can check this: http://codepaste.net/b1geac